# How to create grouped barplot from dataframe grouped by two columns with intervals

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by

I grouped the data by two columns (`'a'` and `'b'`). And for each column, I cut it into bins.
For each crossed bin, I would like to have the sum of `'c'`. Then I want to create a grouped plot for the sum of `'c'`. However, when I use `.plot(kind='bar')` after the grouped data, the bars were not grouped together.

```
grouped = df.groupby([pd.cut(df['a'], [0, 1, 2, 3]), pd.cut(df['b'], [0, 101, 300, 500])])
grouped = grouped.c.sum()
grouped.plot(kind='bar')
```

[ungrouped barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7bHM.png)

I would like the graph to be grouped by `'a'` with different color standing for `'b'`. I have tried `.unstack().plot(kind='bar')`; however, it returns an error:

> cannot determine next label for type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following example data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [8, 49, 81, 52, 22, 24, 32, 67, 24, 21, 78, 16, 86, 19, 4, 88, 4, 20, 20, 1],
                   'b': [2, 49, 49, 70, 31, 47, 98, 26, 55, 36, 17, 39, 56, 80, 52, 36, 42, 69, 73, 70],
                   'c': [22, 99, 31, 95, 16, 32, 81, 20, 58, 23, 53, 5, 0, 81, 8, 68, 16, 36, 35, 54]})
```

and your setup

```
grouped = df.groupby([pd.cut(df['a'], [16, 30, 67, 86]),
                      pd.cut(df['b'], [0, 26, 49, 100])])
grouped = grouped['c'].sum()
```

you have two options

- ```
  (grouped.reset_index()
          .pivot('a', 'b')
          .plot(kind='bar'));
  ```

  [image]
- ```
  grouped = grouped.unstack()
  grouped.columns = grouped.columns.categories
  grouped.plot(kind='bar');
  ```

  [image]